# Javax Crypto - Intrinsic Candidate in AESCrypt.java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, intrinsics

Let's assume I am using the AES-encryption from javax.crypto like this:

```
byte[] plaintext = Files.readAllBytes(...);
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, "AES");
byte[] iv = new byte[] {
                   (byte)0xF0, (byte)0xF1, (byte)0xF2, (byte)0xF3, (byte)0xF4, (byte)0xF5, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0xF7,
                   (byte)0xF8, (byte)0xF9, (byte)0xFA, (byte)0xFB, (byte)0xFC, (byte)0xFD, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0xFF
               };
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
encryptedJavax = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
```

With `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", "SunJCE");` I am making sure that java uses the SunJCE-provider for the implementation of AES-encryption and for the CTR-mode.
The newest code-version of JavaJDK can be found here:
for the AES-Encrypion: [AES-Crypt.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/AESCrypt.java)
and for the CTR-Mode: [CounterMode.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/CounterMode.java)

Lets look at at AES-Crypt.java. The real block-encryption is implemented with this function:

```
// Encryption operation. Possibly replaced with a compiler intrinsic.
    @IntrinsicCandidate
    private void implEncryptBlock(byte[] in, int inOffset,
                                  byte[] out, int outOffset)
...
```

Is there a possibility to check if this function is replaced when I am running `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);` like I showed in the first code example?
What does this IntrinsicCandidate do? Where can I find the implementation for that?
I would like to lookup the code that is used for the encryption when I am running the init-function in order to compare this to another implementation.

the same with the CTR-Mode:

```
 // Implementation of crpyt() method. Possibly replaced with a compiler intrinsic.
    @IntrinsicCandidate
    private int implCrypt(byte[] in, int inOff, int len, byte[] out, int outOff)
```

This method is used for the CTR-Mode, but it may be replaced. I also would like to see if it is really replaced when I am runnig the init-Method.

Comment: Intrinsics are special CPU instructions on _some_ CPUs. _If_ your CPU has these instructions, they will get used when and if these methods are JITted, which definitely won't happen when you call `init` or do one or few blocks of encryption or decryption; it will only happen if and when these methods are executed "a lot", where the definition of "a lot" is tweaked by Sun-now-Oracle on almost every version of Java.